# How can I capture Windows hardware configuration using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, registry

How can I capture the hardware configuration using batch file?

And also want to know the Registry location where hardware configuration information is stored.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you be any more specific than "hardware configuration"? What exactly do you want to log?

Comment: I guess http://superuser.com would be a better place to ask, though I am not sure.

Comment: I want to capture the hardware changes like storage change, N/W card change. 
I am think to do this by capture these info on time base and compare with the old info.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the `systeminfo` command and redirect the output to a file:

```
systeminfo > %computername%-systeminfo.txt.
```

`systeminfo` can also be run on a remote system, and there are several different output formats you can use:

```
SYSTEMINFO [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] [/FO format] [/NH]

Description:
    This command line tool enables an administrator to query for basic
    system configuration information.

Parameter List:
    /S      system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U      [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which
                             the command should execute.

    /P      [password]       Specifies the password for the given
                             user context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /FO     format           Specifies the format in which the output
                             is to be displayed.
                             Valid values: "TABLE", "LIST", "CSV".

    /NH                      Specifies that the "Column Header" should
                             not be displayed in the output.
                             Valid only for "TABLE" and "CSV" formats.

    /?                       Displays this help/usage.

Examples:
    SYSTEMINFO
    SYSTEMINFO /?
    SYSTEMINFO /S system
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /U user
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /U domain\user /P password /FO TABLE
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /FO LIST
    SYSTEMINFO /S system /FO CSV /NH
```